# Why OR condition is not allowed in KeyConditionExpression in Dynamodb and what is the alternative for this

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

OR condition is not allowed in KeyConditionExpression. Is there any alternative for this?

Below is my code :

project_id: Primary Key

project_name: Sort Key

In the UI text box, project name or project id is entered to search a particular project.

```
const param =  {
    "TableName": "Projects",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "project_id = :p OR project_name = :p",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":p": project, //This value is read from UI text box
    }
}

const projects = await dynamodb.query(param).promise();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDb does not support or condition in key condition expression.You have to use two queries for this task.Please go through [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html) for better understanding.